# Storing javascript variables and displaying their values in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, post

I'm new to Javascript and I'm using a website's API to try to get some info about a user once they have gone through the website's authorization process but am having trouble understanding how to store (for later access) the response from the website.

Let's say this is my request for a 'user' object to a website:

```
    // POST for user object 
    $.post("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token", {
        client_id: clientID,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        grant_type : 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        code: user_code},
  function(data) {
    grabUserAccessTok(data);
  });
```

Right now, I'm passing the response to grabUserAccessTok() but what if I wanted to store this response so that I can display all of the responses different attributes at different times on my webpage? How could I store this response? How would I access the stored response to display it on my webpage in, say, a `<div>` element?

Answer (score 2):

You`re already passing the response to a function. This means you already have the data.

**Do note: according to the [twitch API](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md) () you dont get a username from this request.**

So to get the user you need to update your post request.

After you get the post request its fairly easy, Twitch return JSON so you can use [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) to get the data in an object.

```
 // POST for user object 
    $.post("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token", {
        client_id: clientID,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        grant_type : 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        code: user_code},
  function(data) {
var obj = $.parseJSON( data ); //parses the JSON
var user = obj.user; //reads the element user from the JSON
$( body ).append( user ); //I wouldnt advice doing it like this but for demonstrating purposes...
    grabUserAccessTok(data);
  });
```

Best would be to write this code in your grabUserAccessTok and seperate the UI part from the retrieval/parsing part

Answer (score 0):

It is easy:

```
 var response_from_server = null;// variable for storage the response

 // POST for user object 
    $.post("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token", {
        client_id: clientID,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        grant_type : 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        code: user_code},
  function(data) {
    response_from_server = data; // store the response
    grabUserAccessTok(data);
    $("#div_element_id").text(response_from_server.username);//output
  });
```

NOTE:

```
// Step 1:
var response_from_server = null;// variable is defined
// there response_from_server is null
// Step 2:
$.post(...,function(data){
// Step 4:
response_from_server = data; // store the response
// there response_from_server is data, because the POST is finished
});
// Step 3:
// there response_from_server is still null, because POST call in process
```

Comment: Ok, if the data object had a "username" attribute, how could I display data.username in my HTML page?